# IsThere Any way to Get Notifications like this"Good Morning (User Name) "

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am New and Creating Xamarin Forms Application , I need Help to Give Message Like "Good Morning" or "Did You Forget to To Login" message Notification to User.
Thanks In advance

Comment: Take a look at local notifications https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications

Comment: @FLagon First of All thanks for Your Reply sir, I have one doubt can we do this With Timed Notification

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of notification you can choose:

**Local notification**:

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications) is the document, local notification send by applications. It can be time or location based, you can also choose repeat or not by config the notification.

**Remote notification**:

Here is document about remote notification in Xamarin.Android: [Google Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/)

Xamarin.iOS: [about-remote-notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows#about-remote-notifications)

Remote notification send by you. You can choose to send the notification at any time with any content. It is different in iOS and Android. You can read the document for more information.

[Send and receive push notifications with Azure Notification Hubs and Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub)